# SISS and SQL Server CPU Performence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I'm running a 32 core SQL Server Box. Which also runs a SISS Server, where SISS packages are stored and run.

The load on the database is very low, nightly updates, a handfull are tables updated during daytime, and otherwise is just a lot of select statements. Typical DW with a frontend that caches data.

My issues is that when I run a SISS package, in the studio, then it executes within a hour. But if I run it on the SISS Server it runs for hours. The package basically aggregates data from various tables, and places it in one table. Other package of other types, also run very slow when run from SISS Server.

CPU usage is never above 7%, memory is at 29gb of 32 on the server.

Is there a way that I can prioritize CPU away from the SQL Server and over to SISS Server?

I believe CPU priotization is the issue, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Maybe there's something with buffer or network package size settings. And another suggestion is to check queries with Profiler, I believe they would be the same.

Comment: Network and Buffer (Temp File) seem ok, queries execute quickly, when using MSSQL Studio. Its only when SSIS packages run using the SQL Agents they are slow.

Comment: If CPU is never above 7% how have you concluded this is the issue?

Comment: Looking at the CPU monitor, while running a single SSIS package on the server. I'd wish it took more CPU.

Answer (score 1):

When SSIS runs out of memory it will typically slow down a lot before it fails, as it will start writing and reading temp files for some operations.  I suspect this is your problem.

To avoid this I would reduce the maximum Memory allocated to the SQL Server Database Engine, e.g. to 8GB. Obviously you need to consider potential impacts on other SQL Server Database Engine operations, but it usually does surprisingly well with less Memory.

PS: you are admirably consistent with your mis-spelling of SSIS ... :-)